# Proof verification - If g is integrable and $\frac 1g$ is bounded then $\frac 1g $is integrable.

Tags: calculus

**Question:**
Given that if $g$ is integrable, $\frac 1g$ is bounded in $[a,b]$, then $\frac 1g$ is integrable as well.

I would like to verify correctness of this proof. Thanks.
$\omega_i(g) = max(g(x))-min(g(x)) (x \in [x_i,x_{i+1}])$
$\omega_(g)$ the difference between the max and the min of $g$ for the entire $[a,b]$

**Given:**

- Since $g$ is integrable then $\omega(g)<\varepsilon$
  $\forall \varepsilon>0 $ and specifically for $\varepsilon'$=$\varepsilon \over M^2 $
- $|\frac 1g|<M$
- $\omega_i(\frac 1g) =M_i-m_i =\sup |\frac 1{g(y)}-\frac 1{g(x)}|
   \forall x,y\in [x_i, x_{i+1} ]= 
  \sup |\frac {g(x)-g(y)}{g(x)g(y)}|= $
  $\sup |g(x)-g(y)|\cdot \sup |\frac 1{g(x)g(y)}|=\omega_i(g)\sup |\frac 1{g(x)g(y)}| 
  \le M^2\omega_i(g) $
- $\omega (\frac 1g , \Pi)=\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i(\frac 1g)\Delta x_i \le
  \sum_{i=1}^n M^2 \omega_i(g)\Delta x_i =  M^2 \sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i(g)\Delta x_i =
  M^2 \omega (g,\Pi)<\frac {M^2 \varepsilon'} {M^2} =\varepsilon'$ 
  therefore $\frac 1g$ is integrable.

Comment: Please edit the title of the question so it isn't a tautology.

Comment: Please clarify your notation.